# Writing to two different files with HDF5

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, hdf5, storing-data

I've a small library in C that makes use of HDF5 to write data (v. 1.8.14) under Windows. That lib is then used by a C# app that does some other stuff and then needs to write quite a lot of data.

I now need to launch two instances of the application with the idea of having each instance saving to two distinct files placed on two different hard disks. However, I've performance issues and data loss. By inspecting the use of disks, it seems that data is written serially (first HD is busy while the second is not, then the second becomes busy and the first not and so on), which is as having a single disk (and a single disk is not fast enough for twice the data).

So what shall I do to write to two different files from two different processes? Do I need to use [Parallel HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/PHDF5/)? And the solution you are going to propose will also work if I later want to write to two different files from within the same process? Please provide details and links to relevant resources

Comment: If you have two different instances running, then they should be able to write separately, unless your HDF5 code is not contained within the same code that is operating the instances.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to write the files from different appdomains in one process.

Comment: Never spend time writing software to solve a problem which can be solved by hardware, or even by configuration.  If the disks are identical, use them in RAID to double your throughput without having to handle them as separate disks.  If the disks are not identical, then buy two identical disks and set them in RAID.  Buying hardware is usually cheaper than writing software. Researching solutions involving configuration and/or hardware, buying the hardware, and implementing the solutions is _**also**_ usually cheaper than writing software.